# Informal term alternative to attendee

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe people who are attending an event, or who have attended, and would like a less formal term than attendee.

I would strongly prefer a single word to a phase, but can be flexible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Depending on the nature of the event, _guest_ or _participant_ could be appropriate.

Comment: attendant ?....

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing them out there - *audience*, *crowd*, *fans*?

Answer (score 1):

People that attend an event, whether they are active participants or not, are often simply called **guests**.